# want to set read only permission on sd card

Tags: android

I want to set read-only permission on external micro-sd card programatically, and user should not be able to access it form phone menu too.

or Is there another way to hide that, because client have a video folder which is played by only subscribed users, therefore i want that folder is either read-only or hidden for other users.
plz help  .

Answer (score 2):

That is not a sensible way to accomplish what you are trying to do. You should be storing the data encrypted and decrypting it strictly in your application. You will *never* get any kind of 'hiding' to work right.

Comment: plz give me any idea to implement this task.!!

Comment: This is a "build a bridge for vehicle traffic" kind of task. There's no paragraph or two I can give you that will enable you to run off and do it.

Comment: Not possible. The format of SD card is FAT32 and doesn't support that feature. Of course,you can encrypt your file but the user can also delete them.

Comment: if I decrypted the encrypted video file through code then after that, the decrypted file is always available for all.

Comment: I think you missed the "decrypting it *strictly* in your application". That is, the decrypted data *never* leaves your application. You don't write the decrypted data back to storage.

Answer (score 1):

You can't get any kind of this, So if possible store the video in internal storage (but if device can rooted then also user can access it), or store in a web server and at a play time play from web. And only option is as per `David Schwartz` suggested do encryption/Decryption for it.

Comment: if I decrypted the encrypted video file through code then after that, the decrypted file is always available for all.

Answer (score 1):

It's **`not a reasonable way`** to say that **I have some of my apps data in an sd-card, so no one else should access that!**, Better try some alternative like `encrypting your data`, so that even if someone accessed, they must not be able to read it!